# struts 2 doesn't include file ApplicationResources.properties

Tags: java, maven, struts2

I have an application made with struts2.

Since a few days, when I compile it with maven, it doesn't include the file ApplicationResources.properties in .war file.

The configuration in the pom.xml is :

```
              <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-utf8</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                        <includes>ApplicationResources_*.properties</includes>
                        <excludes>ApplicationResources.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_de*.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_fr*.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_nl*.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_pt*.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_es*.properties</excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-8859_1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>8859_1</encoding>
                        <includes>ApplicationResources.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_de.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_fr.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_nl.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_pt*.properties,
                            ApplicationResources_es*.properties</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Comment: They should be `<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>` and `<encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>`

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work

Comment: That was not the answer to your question, I was just warning you of *another* problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it deleting the exclude tag of this file

```
    <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <!-- <excludes>
                <exclude>ApplicationResources*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>-->
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
```